# Mi función no se ejecuta en IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Me despliega un menu, pero no me activa los submenus. En los demas exploradores si funciona. Alguna Idea?

```
function agregaMenuPanel(id, nombre) {
    var panel = Csg.getElement(id);
    if (panel != null) {
        panel.style.display = 'none';
        nombre = nombre.substring(0, 3);
        var val = Default.validarPanel(nombre);
        if (val.value != null) {
            if (val.value == true) {
                Csg.getElement(id).style.display = '';
                var submenu = Default.GetPanelMegaMenu(nombre);
                Csg.getElement(id).innerHTML = submenu.value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, en `var panel = Csg.getElement(id);` no debería ser `var panel = Csg.getElementById(id);`?

Comment: presiona F12 y veamos que error te da

Comment: Ya intente el cambio de getElementById y ni siquiera me abre la pag

Comment: me sale un warning    DOCTYPE HTML5 no válido. Considere el uso del formulario interoperable "<!DOCTYPE html>".

Comment: ¿En versiones anteriores de IE si funciona? ¿funciona si presionan F12 cambias la versión del IE?

Comment: no, tampopo funciona, y me di cuenta q el erro sale q etas no estan implementadas(codigo). pero seguro es por q el js no las implemento

Comment: function ClicMegaMenu(opcion) {
            Csg.getElement('center-iframe').src = opcion;                      
            Csg.getElement('PANEL-BAS-DDC').style = "display: none";
            Csg.getElement('PANEL-RYE-DDC').style = "display: none";            
            Csg.getElement('PANEL-CFG-DDC').style = "display: none";            
        }